# Round vs Rectangular Buttons

Tags: buttons

Is there any published, statistical data or scientific papers that show if **round** buttons are more likely to be tapped than traditional **rectangular** buttons? By round buttons I mean circles, not rectangles with rounded corners but it would be also interesting to read about such.

I am interested especially in data related to mobile applications.

Comment: Are you looking at a single button, or a series of buttons? Round buttons have less hit surface, leaving less space to draw the eye, but a single circular button may draw the eye in an appropriate layout.

Comment: To be valid, the study would have to address also the button's label and not only its shape, wether its rounded or not. Also, the study -to be relevant- would have to address the overall page layout and the copy. You might have to review your question as all these criteria impact the click/tap rate

Comment: I'm looking for any information related to this topic. Especially, surveys, researches, scientific data. Couple of people told me that round objects bring higher conversion rates. I guess there must be some surveys on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Round corners are easier on the eye and make it easier to focus on the button content easier than the square counterparts. But with the way web trends are currently going with flat 2d interfaces, this may change our conditioning over time?

Humans are also conditioned to be more accepting of rounder objects, a good piece from UX movement explaining the psychology behind this thinking:

http://uxmovement.com/thinking/why-rounded-corners-are-easier-on-the-eyes/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just squared of the corners of all my elements in a new interface just this afternoon. I'll be putting the rounding back tomorrow morning now! +1!

Comment: Good answer but please provide an excerpt or gist of the article. This will help the answer be relevant even if the link stops working